# want to parse the xml into java object

Tags: java, arrays, xml

in my case its not full xml instead of that i want to parse the part of one xml tag to be parsed.

```
<FILTERABLE>
    <FILTER_ELEMENT ALIAS_NAME="roomnumber" JOINER="AND" LPAREN="false" OPERATOR="BEGINS" RPAREN="false" SEQNUM="1" VALUE="1001"/>
</FILTERABLE>
```

Please help to convert the code into java object.

```
ByteArrayInputStream bis = new ByteArrayInputStream(filterStrValue.getBytes("UTF-8"));
                    Document document = EntityCollectionXMLUtil.DomfromXML(new InputSource(bis), false);
                    Element rootElement = document.getDocumentElement();
                    rootElement.getElementsByTagName("FILTERABLE")
```

Need one java object as a pair of hash map contains below

```
FILTER_ELEMENT ALIAS_NAME = "roomnumber"
JOINER="AND"
LPAREN="false" 
OPERATOR="BEGINS"
RPAREN="false"
SEQNUM="1"
VALUE="1001"
```

Comment: If you have already written a class for the attributes of the FilterElement, you will be able to use one of [those libraries](https://www.baeldung.com/java-xml-libraries).

Comment: why not use hash map then?

Answer (score 0):

dom4j is an open source, Java-based library for parse XML documents. in this answer used dom4j api for parse the xml document. hence, add the dom4j.jar file into your application's classpath.

class of FILTER_ELEMENT

```
public class Filter_Element {

    private String ALIAS_NAME;
    private String JOINER;
    private Boolean LPAREN;
    private String OPERATOR;
    private Boolean RPAREN;
    private int SEQNUM;
    private int VALUE;

    public String getALIAS_NAME() {
        return ALIAS_NAME;
    }
    public void setALIAS_NAME(String aLIAS_NAME) {
        ALIAS_NAME = aLIAS_NAME;
    }
    public String getJOINER() {
        return JOINER;
    }
    public void setJOINER(String jOINER) {
        JOINER = jOINER;
    }
    public Boolean getLPAREN() {
        return LPAREN;
    }
    public void setLPAREN(Boolean lPAREN) {
        LPAREN = lPAREN;
    }
    public String getOPERATOR() {
        return OPERATOR;
    }
    public void setOPERATOR(String oPERATOR) {
        OPERATOR = oPERATOR;
    }
    public Boolean getRPAREN() {
        return RPAREN;
    }
    public void setRPAREN(Boolean rPAREN) {
        RPAREN = rPAREN;
    }
    public int getSEQNUM() {
        return SEQNUM;
    }
    public void setSEQNUM(int sEQNUM) {
        SEQNUM = sEQNUM;
    }
    public int getVALUE() {
        return VALUE;
    }
    public void setVALUE(int vALUE) {
        VALUE = vALUE;
    }
}
```

attributes values of xml element (FILTER_ELEMENT) set to the filterElement object

```
try {

    File fXmlFile = new File("your_xml_file.xml");
    DocumentBuilderFactory dbFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
    DocumentBuilder dBuilder = dbFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
    Document doc = dBuilder.parse(fXmlFile);
    NodeList nodeList= doc.getElementsByTagName("FILTER_ELEMENT");
    Filter_Element filterElement;

    for(int i = 0; i < nodeList.getLength(); i++) {
        Node node = nodeList.item(i);
        filterElement = new Filter_Element();

        filterElement.setALIAS_NAME(node.getAttributes().getNamedItem("ALIAS_NAME").getNodeValue());
        filterElement.setJOINER(node.getAttributes().getNamedItem("JOINER").getNodeValue());
        filterElement.setLPAREN(Boolean.valueOf(node.getAttributes().getNamedItem("LPAREN").getNodeValue()));
        filterElement.setOPERATOR(node.getAttributes().getNamedItem("OPERATOR").getNodeValue());
        filterElement.setRPAREN(Boolean.valueOf(node.getAttributes().getNamedItem("RPAREN").getNodeValue()));
        filterElement.setSEQNUM(Integer.valueOf(node.getAttributes().getNamedItem("SEQNUM").getNodeValue()));
        filterElement.setVALUE(Integer.valueOf(node.getAttributes().getNamedItem("VALUE").getNodeValue()));
    }

} catch (Exception e) {

    e.printStackTrace();

}
```